# How can I use a custom template file when node_view is executed?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am trying to integrate with a module that uses `drupal_render(node_view($node));` to get a rendered node.  I have a custom template file `node--<type>.tpl.php` that works fine when simply viewing the node, however, when the node is rendered using `node_view` the template file is not used, instead the core `node.tpl.php` in modules/node is used.  I also implemented `hook_preprocess_node` which doesn't appear to fire in this case either.

A simple case to re-create this would be to implement `hook_preprocess_node` and include a watchdog message.  Then execute the following in devel execute php:

```
$node = node_load(<nid>);
print drupal_render(node_view($node));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that at the point the other module was executing the `node_view` function, it was using the administrative theme rather than the public theme.

To eliminate this issue, I implemented `hook_theme_registry_alter` and placed the custom templates in a custom module.  This way they would be used regardless of the theme selected.